# WebView - center Image Content

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a screen/component in React Native that will display an image in the center of the screen and allow pinch/zoom of the image. I have done this previously in roundabout ways with creating multiple nested pinch/pan gesture handlers, but it is cumbersome and I realized that the default web browser of mobile devices have this functionality.

So, I am trying to get this result using [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/). I almost have the results I want using essentially the default setup for Android, but in iOS the image defaults to the top of the screen.

Is there a way to get identical behavior from both Android and iOS? Possibly with properties of the WebView or by creating static HTML to feed to the WebView with styling to get the two to match? I looked through the documentation, but I didn't see anything that stood out to me as what I'm looking for.

Here is my code:

```js
render(){
        return(
            <View style = { styles.mainContainer }>
                <WebView
                    style = { styles.webView }
                    source = {{ uri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/link/to/my/image.png'}}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    webView: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    }
})
```

And here is a side-by-side of how they look:
[image: android vs ios]

Comment: Did you figure out somehow? I have similar problem. Thanks

Comment: @MartinBielak No, sorry, I ended up having to use an imageviewer plugin but it doesn't do exactly what I wanted.